# Uses deprecated APIs 1 warning found Browser errors were logged to the console

Tags: browser, console, deprecated

I have added an image of the WordPress site where I am facing these two issues which are becoming a hurdle in my site to optimize for best practices. I tried to find its solution but got no understanding of how to do that in my website of WordPress.

Uses deprecated APIs 1 warning found
Browser errors were logged to the console

Screenshot from Chrome inbuilt dev tool

[image]

Comment: Have you found the solution

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution by removing this policy from htaccess file. It's an HTTP header. You can check your website **HTTP headers**.

```html
Header set Expect-CT enforce,max-age=2592000,report-uri="https://example.com/"
```

here is some help on this issue I believe.

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/immutable-document-domain/